# How to be more sure or guarantee screen recording will record the audio on iPad / iPhone?

Tags: ios, ipad, screen-recording

I am using iPad Pro (first gen) with iOS 12.0.1. If I try to record a game, such as Plants vs Zombies using the iOS built in function of screen recording, I found that often there is no audio recorded. Sometimes it is recorded, if I am "lucky".

So I can be playing for 7, 8 minutes, to beat a level, and get ready to post on YouTube, and then found that there is no audio. And then, try for another 7, 8 minutes and see if it is another 7, 8 minutes wasted.

I have also tried: start the screen recording first, and then start the game, or the other way around: start the game first, and then start the screen recording. But neither can guarantee audio is recorded.

How can it be made to work?

P.S. I recorded one clip, and was so happy that I heard the audio while watching the recorded clip of the gameplay, but until about 27 seconds later the audio all of a sudden disappeared. So the recording is again useless. The key point is that the audio can spontaneously disappear.

Comment: Does this audio/no audio problem happen when you try to record other activities on the iPad, or just "Plants vs. Zombies"?

Comment: so far, Plants vs Zombies is the only thing I needed to record. I can try, but are you suggesting PvZ can be outputting a different type of audio? Some kind of audio that can bypass the OS's control and it is not recorded?

Comment: No idea what PvZ is doing. Just trying to give you a troubleshooting tip to see if the problem is unique to PvZ or a system-wide problem.

Comment: Does the issue have to do with Silent Mode being enabled, or your volume being turned all the way down?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder if I don't hear audio during the gameplay, I wouldn't expect the recording to have audio